# Make Swagger use primitive int and boolean in generated models

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger, primitive

By default, for "type": "boolean" in JSON spec, Swagger will generate a `Boolean` (object, non-primitive, nullable) field in model.
Is there a way to make Swagger generate `boolean` (primitive, non-nullable) fields in models instead?

The rationale is: Spring MVC is going to initialize these fields with `null` on invalid input, which is soooo undesirable. Better keep them with default values.

Same question with `int` vs `Integer`.

NB: Swagger has its own concept of "primitive" types which is totally unrelated to Java primitives and isn't what I seek.

Comment: Are you using springfox?

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich No, and I don't know what it is

Comment: I decided to make a research for both cases anyway:)

Comment: Why do you care about Spring initializing fields to null, when the whole request should be deemed invalid and thrown out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like it is impossible.

I took a look at [`swagger-core`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core) and [`springfox`](https://github.com/springfox/springfox)(Swagger for Spring based API). The thing I did is just found source code for converting/translating primitive types.

So in [`swagger-core`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core) I found [`PrimitiveType`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-core/src/main/java/io/swagger/util/PrimitiveType.java) enum. As you can see there is no primitive Java types mentioned, all the swagger types are mapped to Java wrappers. Taking into account that this enum is used internally and cannot be replaced (unless you make your own version) I assume it is impossible to change this type resolving behaviour.

Same in [`springfox`](https://github.com/springfox/springfox). I found [`TypeNameExtractor`](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/springfox-schema/src/main/java/springfox/documentation/schema/TypeNameExtractor.java) that uses `fasterxml`'s [`TypeResolver`](https://github.com/FasterXML/java-classmate/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/classmate/TypeResolver.java) class for resolving types. This class  in its turn uses [`ResolvedPrimitiveType`](https://github.com/FasterXML/java-classmate/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/classmate/types/ResolvedPrimitiveType.java) to get type mapping. As you can see, type resolving also is deep enough so I suppose there is also no way to change it somehow.

Hope you find my findings helpful.